# Dupe hammer missed the target?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Let's start by saying that I'm loving the new gold badge duplicate hammer!

However, when visiting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23666045/why-am-i-getting-a-mysql-fetch-array-warning), which is obviously a duplicate, the hammer fails =(

My logical assumption is that when the question tags match the hammer, it will work, so why doesn't it?

I did notice that the original question didn't bear the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag and was later added on, which could be an explanation; is that deliberately done to prevent users from adding a tag (for which they have a gold badge) just so that they can close it in one go? Or dare I say it's a bug? :)

Comment: This is precisely why [I said this tag-based dupe hammer is not a good idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/230882#comment758444_230882).

Comment: Perhaps it's time to add subordinate tags? (e.g. any question tagged "c++11" is automatically considered to be tagged "c++")

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*It should be noted that the functionality has changed since this Meta posting was made: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308573/. Current tags not added by the hammer wielder are used.*

---

The dupe hammer is only effective for questions where the first revision includes the tag for which you have a gold badge.

[Shog explains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230882/140890) why this choice was made:

> ...this power should be based on the tags in the first revision of the question. I know, that cuts out a lot of potentially-useful effects when it comes to niche tags - but it also cuts out a ton of potential for abuse...

This question [was edited *after* posting to include [php]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230882/140890); only someone with a gold [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays), [warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/warnings), or [fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fetch) badge can wield the hammer here.

Comment: Though, in this case it was obviously a n00b mistake to not tag it with php :)

Comment: Indeed, it was.

Comment: So, the question is then whether this was done on purpose to prevent the scenario I have described?

Comment: It's deliberate, and yes, it's to prevent "this question sucks/I hate this person/I'm having a bad day, I will add my gold tag and close it, then remove the tag". Edited to include Shog's initial statement on that aspect.

Comment: Right. Thanks for digging up that info, guess I failed to read the small inscriptions on the side of that hammer ;-)

Comment: Ah, nice, so I can prevent the hammer by posting with low traffic tags and afterwards editing ;)

Comment: A simple solution to keep all of your question safe now is to tag all of your question badly first and then tag it correctly on a second revision?

Comment: Note: the policy changed 2015-10 to use current tags as long as you have not added your gold tag - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now/268281#268281

Comment: @Ja͢ck the mighty Mjölnir foiled by a noob's negligence. _"Rest easy, noob; I'll take it from here! Err... no... no, wait... my bad... I can't. You see, my godly powers only work within certain parameters..."_

Answer (score 2):

Dupe hammer applies to tags on the post's first revision (which didn't have the php tag). While you have a gold php badge, you don't have a gold badge for the any other tags.