# Allow dupe hammer for required tag(s)

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, tags, dupehammer

Closely related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307579/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now

I understand that it is by design that editing question's tags suppresses the dupe hammer.

[image]

When the edit introduces required tag(s), the dupe hammer should not be suppressed. For example, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033236/order-by-in-the-nested-select-statement) question, OP simply tagged [oracle11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle11g). However, we usually suggest that it should also include the [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) tag as well. It is also clearly mentioned in the respective [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle11g/info). In this case, the question requires two additional tags: [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) and [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)

It is not difficult to understand that **database product related tags** will be closely related to **sql**, **plsql** etc. tags.

I personally think, there should be an exception to this rule, at least allow the required tags. Or based on the user's badges, system should allow the dupe hammer for such useful edits.

I am not straight away tagging this question as *feature-request*, as I would first like to see the community's suggestions.

---

**Outstanding question:**

If I understand correctly, if I also have a Gold badge for the newly added tag, then I could use the dupe hammer even after editing the question.

**Seems I can't**

If I add the tag, then I can't. It has been recently added as per [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307650/3989608).

Comment: Personally, I'd rather see it work like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303938/only-prohibit-those-who-edited-the-tags-from-using-the-dupe-hammer/304032#304032)

Comment: @RobertLongson We could at least have some exceptions to this rule. To be specific, on very rare occasions you would see a database product tag not requiring a sql tag.

Comment: @downvoter, please comment. After all this is a discussion. no point in just downvoting and not explaining the views. Downvote in meta means disagreement, irrespective whether right/wrong, so the opinion matters.

Comment: Your actual question is _"Can we add implied tags, like `oracle11g` implies `oracle`"_ and that has been discussed to death.

Comment: @CodeCaster Not really. Although implied tags should not stop use of dupe hammer. I have updated my question.

Comment: It is bizarre to see downvotes when most of us are unaware of this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307650/3989608

Comment: @LalitKumarB We'll be publishing a meta announcement shortly. Sorry about the delay!

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Thank you! I guess downvoters are confused/unaware of it(that's absolutely fine with me). Could you add it as an answer?

Comment: Cerbrus' post is accurate on all counts. Not sure I'd have much to add!

Comment: Related MSE request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266938/give-lesser-tag-badge-holders-dupehammer-privileges-if-they-have-a-gold-badge-in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How would the system know what "required" tags are?

The tags you have a gold badge in, are added because *you* added them in (indirectly). This means you can no longer cast a binding close-vote based on those tags.

This is a recent addition to SO / SE, explained a bit in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307650/1835379) by [Thomas Orozco♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/873145/thomas-orozco):

> If you cast a close vote that would have been binding had you not changed the tags yourself, there'll be a message explaining that as well (instead of simply telling you *"your vote has been recorded"*).

Basically, this is by design.

The binding close votes now also take the current tags on the question into account. The downside is that you can't cast a binding close vote on questions on which you edited the tags.

---

> *"If I understand correctly, if I also have a Gold badge for the newly added tag, then I could use the dupe hammer even after editing the question."*

- If you added the tag: No, you can't.
- If someone else added that tag: You can.

Comment: I understand it is by design. I was expecting if mostly related tags could be allowed, like SQL related to database products. Anyway, I just have an outstanding question. I have updated the question.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Updated my answer.

Comment: Ah! I got my answer "If someone else added that tag: You can.". Thank you. This "*If you added a tag that results in that tag being added as well: No, you can't.*" is not clear. A small example please. In any case, your answer is accepted.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: hm, that was a bad example, removed it.