# I edited the tags but didn't lose my ability to hammer

Tags: support, dupehammer

Here are some excerpts from pages describing Mjölnir:

> It now lets you single-handedly close as duplicate unless you have participated in editing the tag (either by adding the tag yourself, or approving an edit that did). - [*Thomas Orozco*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308573/2301450)

> ... except for duplicate questions, which can be marked as duplicate with a single vote from a user who has earned a gold tag badge in one of that question's current tags, unless that user participated in editing the tags - [*Help center > Privileges*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

> Your [tag] badge usually lets you single-handedly close [tag]
>   questions as duplicates and reopen them. However, since you
>   participated in editing this question's tags, this privilege doesn't
>   apply this time. - *The blue message box*

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29932926/revisions) initially had the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag but the OP approved the edit that removed it. I added it back and single-handedly closed the question as duplicate. Apparently, I was allowed to do so because [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) was one of the question's original tags.

Is this the correct behaviour? If yes, those pages seem somewhat misleading, as none of them explain what happened here. Could they be improved?

Comment: Well, you _were_ the one who did the last tag edit, so according to that quote, the system should look at the original tags. Whether "original" refers to the "first" or rather "previous" revision might be up for debate...

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks, I misinterpreted the answer I cited... Anyway, I edited my question a bit

Comment: I would say it's pretty reasonable behaviour if the only prohibited scenario is hammering with a tag that you have put on the question for the first time, "out of the blue". I suspect that if the tag is present at any point in the earlier history of the question, you can hammer away.