# Dupe Hammer Quirk when editing a question's tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, dupehammer

I fully understand that if I edit a question's tags by adding a tag I normally have dupe hammer privileges for, my dupe hammer isn't honored in such a case (presumable to avoid abuse). That's fine.

But I just edited a question that was mistagged. One of the original tags happened to be one of my gold tags. But I removed that tag as part of the edit. As it happened, I added two new tags that I also happen to have as my gold tags. Those tag edits were done as a single edit - removed one gold tag, added two other gold tags.

I then voted to close as a duplicate and I was told my gold tag privileges (based on one of the new tags I added) doesn't count in this case. I get that due to the normal rules.

But why ignore the fact that one of the original tags is one of my gold tags? I'm assuming the vote to close only looks at the current tags and not the original tags. If I voted to close before editing, my dupe hammer privileges would have closed the question.

Any chance this can be changed in an enhancement?

In other words, if someone votes to close after having editing the question's tags, can the logic be updated to check the original tags in addition to the new tags?

Comment: For additional context/background: looks like the gold-badger loses its dupe-hammer *after doing any edits to tags*: "*It now lets you single-handedly close as duplicate **unless you have participated in editing the tag (either by adding the tag yourself, or approving an edit that did).***" (ref: [Only prohibit those who edited the tags from using the dupe hammer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308573))

Comment: @AndrewT. I covered that in the opening paragraph of my question. That's why this is a feature request to look at the original tags, not just the newly added tags.

Comment: I know you from our shared tags of course, and completely trust your duplicate judgement, but I doubt this will get much traction. If the original tag was removed, then it must have been incorrect. Making the system understand that e.g., [xcode] is mis-applied to [ios] questions all the time such that the original tag should count for dupehammering doesn't seem feasible. (The ideal would be to accept that us gold badgers actually are trustworthy and [just lift the editing restriction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304032/).)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks and you are probably right. I've edit the tags of many thousands of questions and I think this is the first time I've ever removed one gold tag and replaced it with another and then followed it with a duplicate close vote so it caught my attention. But I get this would be a low priority over other changes. BTW - I miss your fantastic duplicate finding skills. It's been a while.

Comment: Appreciated! The site has unfortunately been more frustration than fun for me lately, so I've been spending some time away.

Comment: This just bit me too.  Now we have to try to remember to dupe-hammer *before* fixing the tags -- which means that **a wasteful reopen review will also be triggered**.