# Question dupehammered with tag added in edit?

Tags: support, dupehammer

Some user added the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35974102/revisions) after I voted to close as duplicate.

Another user then close-voted the question as well, and now the question page shows it's been dupehammered by the last user - because they hold a gold badge for the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag.

Shouldn't the dupe-vote count *not* work as dupehammer-vote when the tag was later edited in, as explained in [Dupe hammer missed the target?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254917/dupe-hammer-missed-the-target)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dupehammer [was changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now/268281#268281) after its original implementation.

> ...we now look at the question's current tags instead of its original tags, unless you were the one that edited them (either by doing it yourself, or by approving an edit from someone else).

Comment: Silly me, didn't notice that for five months.