# Dupehammer doesn't work after tags removed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed, dupehammer

I  voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56821325/10221765) because I believed it to be an asynchronous call with `fetch`. Turns out the GAS (Google Apps Script) `fetch` is synchronous, so people pinged me asking for a reopen. I responded (kinda late due to my timezone and other things), and voted to reopen the question, however as the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag had been edited out, my vote was treated as any other - it was placed in the `reopen` queue.

Now, according to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254918/10221765), the dupe hammer wielders are determined upon the *first revision* of the post. Voilà [la première révision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56821325/1):

[image: First revision]

As you can see, there is the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag in the question in the original revision. But in a later revision, the tag was removed, and now my effort at reopening it seems to not have been effective. Why are the rules for reopening questions different for closing, and if they are, what *exactly* are they?

Comment: Josh's answer there says that his description below is outdated, and points [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now), which says *we now look at the question's current tags instead of its original tags*. I remember a few times where someone else *added* a tag not present in the original post, and I was able to dupehammer immediately after due to that tag, so I think the post's original tags do not matter at all now, and all it takes into consideration is the current tags. Not 100% sure though

Comment: That would make sense @CertainPerformance - would you agree this question be reopened? (I could edit the tags to allow your hammer to work.)

Comment: Think so, [`UrlFetchApp.fetch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241396/is-google-apps-script-synchronous) looks to be synchronous

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is working as designed since the [dupehammer requirements were changed to use the current tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268281):

> [W]e now look at the question's *current* tags instead of its *original tags*, unless *you* were the one that edited them (either by doing it yourself, or by approving an edit from someone else).

The [answer you link to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254918) points to the same information, at the top:

> *It should be noted that the functionality has changed since this Meta posting was made: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308573/. Current tags not added by the hammer wielder are used.*

That link there leads to a post by Thomas Orozco who then links to the same post I quoted above.

I’ve cast a binding reopen vote to add to yours and two other reopen votes.

Comment: This seems like an edge case that really should work differently. It doesn't make sense to prevent users from undoing *only their own* actions. It's less clear how to handle cases where other people voted to close in addition to the gold badge holder, but I'm inclined to say just allow the gold badge holder to single-handedly reopen such questions, for consistency and simplicity.

Comment: @Dukeling: Shog is open to suggestions: [Can't single-handedly reopen a dupehammered Q after editing gold tag to another gold tag](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/269103)

Comment: Wouldn't this enable users to edit their questions to only have some obscure tag that noone has a golden badge for so the questions wouldn't be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @JL2210 No. Closing any post takes just 5 users, including non-gold-badge duplicate closing. Editing a post to correct the tags and then dupe hammering takes just 2 users. And any user that does this, using an obscure tag, is only shooting themselves in the foot because *no one will find it to answer the post*. And moderators will not magically ignore users that repeatedly tried to do this, obscure tags don’t make a user invisible:-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see that now. It was probably worse before, as a user could ask a question in an obscure, unrelated tag and then change the tags to be correct.